Counter Strike 2 doesn't start with the error "Failed to initialize Vulkan"
I can't launch Counter Strike 2 on my Dell laptop, with Intel Haswell-ULT graphics, running Linux Mint. When I try I get an error telling me to check if my GPU supports Vulkan 1.2+:

System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-113-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.4.0 Desktop: MATE 1.26.0
    info: mate-panel wm: marco 1.26.0 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Latitude E7440 v: 00 serial: <superuser required> Chassis:
    type: 9 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Dell model: 091TRH v: A00 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Dell v: A28
    date: 06/13/2019
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i5-4300U bits: 64 type: MT MCP smt: enabled arch: Haswell
    rev: 1 cache: L1: 128 KiB L2: 512 KiB L3: 3 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2694 high: 2852 min/max: 800/2900 cores: 1: 2736 2: 2594 3: 2852 4: 2595
    bogomips: 19953
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel ports:
    active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1,HDMI-A-1,HDMI-A-2 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0a16 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Microdia Integrated Webcam type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 2-4:2
    chip-ID: 0c45:64d2 class-ID: 0e02
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: marco v: 1.26.0 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1366x768 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 361x203mm (14.2x8.0") s-diag: 414mm (16.3")
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: Chi Mei Innolux res: 1366x768 hz: 60 dpi: 112
    size: 309x174mm (12.2x6.9") diag: 355mm (14") modes: 1366x768
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 24.2~git2407100600.ae3e0a~oibaf~j (git-ae3e0ae 2024-07-10 jammy-oibaf-ppa)
    compat-v: 4.6 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:03.0 chip-ID: 8086:0a0c class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: Intel 8 Series HD Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
    chip-ID: 8086:9c20 class-ID: 0403
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-113-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I218-LM vendor: Dell driver: e1000e v: kernel port: f080
    bus-ID: 00:19.0 chip-ID: 8086:155a class-ID: 0200
  IF: eno1 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 7260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1
    bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:08b1 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci v: 3.0 port: f060
    bus-ID: 00:1f.2 chip-ID: 8086:282a rev: N/A class-ID: 0104
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 152.01 GiB (32.6%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD5000LPVX-75V0TT0 size: 465.76 GiB
    speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: HDD rpm: 5400 serial: <filter> rev: 1A01 scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 456.89 GiB used: 152 GiB (33.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 11.9 MiB (2.3%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 235.2 MiB (11.5%) priority: -2 file: /swapfile
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: Full speed or root hub ports: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002
    class-ID: 0900
  Hub-2: 1-1:2 info: Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub ports: 8 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
    chip-ID: 8087:8000 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-3: 2-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 9 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 2-2:3 info: USB Optical Mouse type: Mouse driver: hid-generic,usbhid interfaces: 1
    rev: 1.1 speed: 1.5 Mb/s power: 100mA chip-ID: 30fa:0300 class-ID: 0301
  Device-2: 2-4:2 info: Microdia Integrated Webcam type: Video driver: uvcvideo interfaces: 2
    rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s power: 500mA chip-ID: 0c45:64d2 class-ID: 0e02
  Hub-4: 3-0:1 info: Super-speed hub ports: 4 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0003
    class-ID: 0900
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 58.0 C mobo: 44.0 C sodimm: SODIMM C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 4709
Repos:
  Packages: 2402 apt: 2393 flatpak: 9
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https: //packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb https: //mirror.albony.xyz/linuxmint virginia main upstream import backport
    2: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-graphics-drivers-jammy.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/oibaf-graphics-drivers-jammy.gpg] https: //ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg] http: //repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https: //repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-focal.sources
    1: deb [arch=amd64 i386] https: //dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal main
Info:
  Processes: 222 Uptime: 3h 9m wakeups: 1 Memory: 7.66 GiB used: 2.29 GiB (29.9%) Init: systemd
  v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 alt: 11/12 Client: Unknown python3.10 client
  inxi: 3.3.13

Result from vulcaninfo:
$ vulcaninfo | grep "Vulkan Instance Version" 

WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance: Failed to CreateInstance in ICD 2. 

Skipping ICD. WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance:

 Failed to CreateInstance in ICD 4. Skipping ICD. 

MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete

 Vulkan Instance Version: 1.3.20


Please [edit] your question and give us more details. What is your operating system (mention it in the question, not as a tag)? What is your hardware? What graphics card? What driver? Are you usig steam native or runtime? Try running steam from the terminal and then starting the game. Any useful error messages? Have you done what the message tells you? Did you check if your graphics card supports Vulkan 1.2+?

@terdon i have added the info i just copy and past i am very new in linux

Please open a terminal, run vulkaninfo | grep "Vulkan Instance Version" and add the output to your question. However, is this really a Dell Latitude E7440? That is more than 10 years old! Don't expect modern games to work on such an old machine. If you look at the hardware requirements, you don't even have enough RAM for it, and I suspect your CPU is too old and your graphics card as well. You can't run modern games on ancient hardware, I'm afraid.

@terdon it show me this vulkaninfo | grep "Vulkan Instance Version"
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance: Failed to CreateInstance in ICD 2.  Skipping ICD.
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance: Failed to CreateInstance in ICD 4.  Skipping ICD.
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
Vulkan Instance Version: 1.3.204

@terdon yes sir it is dell latitude E7440 sir but i am able to play this game in windows

Please add all new information to the question. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. But yes, it looks like Vulkan support is incomplete for your hardware. I fear this won't work on Linux, but I don't know enough to be sure.

Your GPU doesn't support (the required version of) Vulkan under Linux.
The game works on Windows because it uses the Direct3D 11 codepath by default. I'm quite sure it won't run in Vulkan mode either.
You may try to run the Windows version of the game under Linux under Wine which uses the OpenGL translation layer for all versions of DirectX up to 11 but I guess this won't work.
Lastly your GPU is 100% insufficient to get playable framerates. You won't get even 30 fps in 800x600 resolution. You need to upgrade your hardware.

Thanks for info. now i know  really need to upgrade the hardware
